# Botched TCP wrapper remotely; how can I connect? Haste is needed

Tags: ssh, tcp

I am trying to help a colleague connect locally to a linux machine (I believe Debian), which uses TCP wrapper for security.

I ssh'd onto the computer and tried to give him access by clearing the contents of /etc/hosts.allow, but failed to make any changes to /etc/hosts.deny. Unfortunately, there were some un-commented-out lines in the /etc/hosts.deny file, but I don't remember what they were. I.e., the file was not empty

As a result, I can no longer ssh onto it, but get this error:
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

He tried ssh-ing onto eth1 (local IP), but this also wasn't successful:
resource temporarily unavailable

So... now we're both locked out. How can I access this computer? Or how can I instruct him to access it?

Thanks!

Comment: So you cleared the hosts that were allowed to connect to your system? You are going to need to go to the physical machine and reverse the changes you made.  There is no solving the problem you describe remotely, since you cannot provide, which hosts are explicitly listed in the list of in the deny host file.

Comment: So if the machine is physical, you need to go to the console. If it is a virtual machine, you can likely access the console remotely still but from the hypervisor server management interface. You might need to ask your server administrators to allow you physical access at the console to login or else see if you can access from the hypervisor UI if that's applicable in your environment. In terms of remote SSH access, you are out of luck.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I will need to connect to the console. Bummer. Thanks for the help, all.